# Unable to give reference for VLOOKUP on special cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to you vlookup on the specials where we have N/A in prior column but not able to succeed as cell reference for vlookup is creating or problem and i tried to research it and fix it but couldn't get the right one. Would be helpful if any of you can help me to correct it

N/A can be in any of the cells in column K and once i filter column k with N/A's here and need to vlookup in column L using below formula on the special cells which are filtered but i am facing challenge with giving vlookup reference cell for which i need to your assistance as N/A can be in K2/K16/K20/K50/K80

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D16,'BP Scoping'!A:B,2,0),D16)

```
'Second vlookup not working
With Sheets("Sheet4")
    Dim LRW As Long
    LRW = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="#N/A"

     'need to check for right cells which is missing
     'One way tried to use this
     .Range(.Range("L2"), Cells(LRW, "L")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=iferror(VLOOKUP($D2,'BP Scoping'!A:B,2,0),D2)"
```

Another way I tried to use this:

```
     .Range("L2:L" & LRW).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=iferror(VLOOKUP($D2,'BP Scoping'!A:B,2,0),D2)"
```

Comment: Do you mean `N/A` as text or `#N/A` as an Excel worksheet error code?

Comment: @ Jeeped - I am using a formula the below formula to check if the result is alpha numberic or not in the respective cells. If its N/A it not alpha numeric for me and for these i should be performing vlookup by filtering =IF(OR(J8="",SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},J8)))),"GEMS ID","N/A").

Comment: *Cell reference for vlookup is creating or problem*  << What does this actually mean. I'm not understanding what your problem is. Do you get an error message? If so, please indicate what error & what line raises the error.

Comment: @ David Zemens - its not throwing error but giving me wrong results as before filtering i dont know which cell as N/A but i tried using D2 as starting to check it might work but its pulling me D2/d16 data only but i wanted to have the data for N/A but i dont now which cell has N/A so want to have cell reference which it can trace out all N/A'S and vlookup to those cells here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last effort was getting close but you need to use **xlR1C1** referencing, not **xlA1** referencing in the formula.

```
.Range("L2:L" & LRW).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = _
   "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC4, 'BP Scoping'!C1:C2, 2, FALSE),RC4)"
```

That should provide the correct references to the values in column D relative to where the formula is placed in column L.

---

<sub>fwiw, you can quickly switch back and forth from **xlA1** to **xlR1C1** referencing  with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd> then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Jeeped :) i got it and thanks for giving the short codes to change format to R1C1 which i never used too. Thanks again and have a wonderful day :)